# The WeTab will run Android applications but uses an Atom CPU. What does this mean for NDK and MonoDroid?

Tags: android, x86, arm, android-ndk, xamarin.android

I'm guessing MonoDroid compiles directly into ARM code. And the NDK, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the NDK was released, part of the vision was to provide support for multiple binaries for different architectures. AFAIK, that's not available today, so we have to hope it becomes available in the not-too-distant future.

MonoDroid seems dependent upon the NDK, so it too will be limited until NDK multi-architecture support is ready.